# Azure search Synonyms implementation using SXA 1.9 and Sitecore 9.2 using postman API

Tags: sxa, sitecore-client, azure-search, paas, api

I have requirement to work with the synonyms for the similar group of words in search.

I did load the synonyms using Postman API to SXA web index and able to see them on the index.

For example: home, house and residence etc.

I was able to query the index on the Azure portal with the synonym words like home and house returns the same results.

**Create Synonym Map:**

https://domain.search.windows.net/synonymmaps?api-version=2019-05-06

`{
   "name":"mysynonymmap",
   "format":"solr",
   "synonyms": "
      home, house, raju, loan\n
      variable, difference, gap\n
      interest, percentage, borrowing, lending\n
      Washington, Wash., WA => WA\n"
}`

**Add synonym map to SXA web index:**  Applied to multiple fields content_s, title etc

https://domain.search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-sxa-web-index?api-version=2019-05-06&allowIndexDowntime=true

 `{
            "name": "sxacontent",
            "type": "Collection(Edm.String)",
            "searchable": true,
            "filterable": false,
            "retrievable": true,
            "sortable": false,
            "facetable": false,
            "key": false,
            "indexAnalyzer": null,
            "searchAnalyzer": null,
            "analyzer": null,
            "synonymMaps": ["mysynonymmap"]
        },`

**Query the SXA Web Index:**

https://domain.search.windows.net/indexes/sitecore-sxa-web-index/docs?search=raju&api-version=2019-05-06

For the search keyword "raju" I can see the results.

When it comes to application the synonyms are not working. I mean the home is the only word that will be part of content and that works but the other synonyms are not giving any results.

Anyone come across the similar situation?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I see no takers on this question. Anyway, thank you for formatting the question Jitendra.